# How do you make a "game" that takes a random element from the list and ask for a guess input on which index that element is on?

Tags: python, class, object, indexing

If I for example have the class:

```
class A:
    def _init_(self, letter, number, index)
        self.letter = letter
        self.number = number
        self.index = index
```

I have this list(could be much longer), example:

```
list = [['D', 123], ['B', 133], ['C',229], ['A', 189], ['F', 630], ['K', 278], ['V', 780], ['O', 819], ['L', 200], ['N', 982], ['M', 562], ['P', 628], ['T', 299]]
```

(The numbers in the list should not matter in these questions, they have to be there for now. Only the letters are important.)

Menu:

```
def menu():
    print("a. Number game")
    print("b. Letter game")
    choice = input("what's your choice?: ")
    return choice
```

It should have the functions that are called when you choose that option:

```
def number_game(): 
    pass

def letter_game():
    pass
```

If you choose the option "a" I want the program to choose (slump) a random letter from the list and make the user guess on which index of the list they are. For example question: "In which place is the letter A?", the answer should be an index number(place) the user thinks A is on. If the answer is right the program should go on with the next question asking about a random letter again and so on until the user decides to quit.

If you choose the option "b" I want the program to do the exact opposite. The program should ask "which letter is on the second place?" and the input should be a letter.
How could you make this work? Thankful for any help!

Comment: Why bother with a list of letters and numbers at all? In the end it's a dice roll.

Answer (score -1):

For option a, you could pick a random letter from the list and then check if the value your user picks is equal to the target value.

For option b, you could get input from the user and use an argmax function to determine if the user input matches the target index.